# Microservice Authentication with API Gateway

Tags: authentication, microservices, api-gateway

I'm in the progress of implementing a microservices architecture with a single entry endpoint for my clients, a API Gateway. This is my suggested authentication flow:

1). Client (SPA) passes user credentials to the API Gateway, which passes them further to my Authorization/Authentication Services.

2). The Auth Service validates credentials and issues some form of opaque token, which is passed back to the client through the API Gateway.

3). The Client sends the token as a header to each request. The API Gateway exchanges this opaque token to a JWT from the Auth Server and stores it in a cache. The JWT is then attached to all downstreaming requests and my internal microservices validates the JWT (Issuer, Audience).

I'm in doubt if any OAuth/OpenID protocols supports this out of the box or if I would have to implement this my self. (Not desirable!). 
Would it be a better solution if the Authentication Service was located outside of the API Gateway?

Thanks in advance.